# Spring Form combine tTwo inputs in one path

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, model

I have this model:

```
public class User{

private String name;
private String Organization;
private Strin OS;

..Setter and Getters
}
```

And this form:

```
<form:form commandName="User" method="post">
<label for="name">Name:</label>
<form:input path="name" />
<form:errors path="name"></form:errors>

<br />
<label for="name">Organization:</label>
<form:input path="organization" />
<form:errors path="organization"></form:errors>
```

can I add an input "Lastname" and then combine with input "name" into a path="name" ?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use regular HTML input tags, making the name a hidden field.  Then use JavaScript to assemble the name from the other fields and post the form.  Spring does not have any means to take two fields and combine them into one on the binding.  At least not that I know of.